# Maven archetype to create a groovy project

Tags: maven, groovy

I am looking to create a maven `groovy` project using some sort of maven archetype. Typically in Java project the directories generated are:

- `src/main/java`
- `src/main/resources`
- `src/test/java`
- `src/test/resources`

Is there a maven archetype that can generate a convention project by similar conventions, perhaps that has `src/main/groovy` and `src/test/groovy`? Something that IDEs such as IntelliJ may auto-detect as a groovy project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with one of the available here? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.maven.archetypes

For instance by running:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.groovy.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=gmaven-archetype-basic -DarchetypeVersion=1.0
```

after running `mvn archetype:generate` add the lines below to the pom.xml file to set java version to 8 or higher.

```xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.java.version>8</project.java.version>
        <project.javabin.version>8</project.javabin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

You can also see the following post: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-java-applications.